# return false not preventing form from submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to validate a field using `$.get` request. I can see the error message("Plan already present") but the form is getting submitted. I want to prevent form from submitting. Here is my code:

```
$("#add_plan_subscriptions").submit(function(event) {
    var flag = true;
    var subdomain_val = $('[name="plan[subdomain_type_id]"]').val();
    var plan_val = $('[name="plan[plan_type_id]"]').val();
    var plan_name = $('[name="plan[plan_name]"]').val();
    var subdomain_type_id = subdomain_val;
    var plan_name = $('[name="plan[plan_name]"]').val();
    $.get("/plans/check_duplicate_plan",{subdomain_type_id: subdomain_type_id, plan_name: plan_name}, function (response) {
      if (response){
        event.preventDefault() ;
        var element = $('[name="plan[plan_name]"]');
        var message = "Plan already present";
        addError(element,message)
        return false;
      }
      else{
        var element = $('[name="plan[plan_name]"]');
        removeError(element)
      }
    })
    if(subdomain_val == ""){
      var element = $('[name="plan[subdomain_type_id]"]')
      var message = "Please select user type"
      addError(element,message)
      flag = false;
    } 
    if(subdomain_val != ""){
      var element = $('[name="plan[subdomain_type_id]"]')
      removeError(element)
    }
    if(plan_val == ""){
      var element = $('[name="plan[plan_type_id]"]')
      var message = "Please select plan type"
      addError(element,message)
      flag = false;
    } 
    if(plan_val != ""){
      var element = $('[name="plan[plan_type_id]"]')
      removeError(element)
    }
    if (!flag){
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: It's because the `return false` in the `$.get` is returning from your anonymous function, not the `submit` handler.

Comment: have you tried to look at your console after submitting?

Answer (score 2):

Now `$.get` calling in `async` mode before response of `GET` your form submit function is calling.
So use `ajax` in `sync` mode instead `$.get`

```
            $.ajax({
                url: '/plans/check_duplicate_plan',
                data: { subdomain_type_id: subdomain_type_id, plan_name: plan_name},
                dataType: 'json',
                async:false,
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response){
                       event.preventDefault() ;
                       var element = $('[name="plan[plan_name]"]');
                       var message = "Plan already present";
                       addError(element,message)
                       return false;
                    }
                    else{
                        var element = $('[name="plan[plan_name]"]');
                        removeError(element)
                    }
                }
            })
```

Comment: Not recommended, the newest versions of jQuery have even dropped off the sync mode from `$.ajax()`.

Answer (score 1):

Steps:
1.Change input type submit to button type
2.Add this line instead of return true in javascript

```
 document.forms["signup"].submit();
```

> I Had a similar problem. Consider a html like this..

```
<form name="login" action="ValidateLogin">
 <button id="SignIn">Login</button>
    </form>
```

> Then Submit the form in javascript where you want your form to return true

```
$.ajax({
>             type: "GET",
>             url: "ManageForm",
>             data: dataString,
>             beforeSend: function()
>             {
> 
> 
>             },
>             success: function(data)
>             {
>                 if (data == 1)
>                 {   alert("data :"+data);
>                     document.getElementById("errorName").innerHTML = "Sorry! UserName Already Taken";
>                     flag = 0;
>                     return false;
>                     
>                 }
>                 else if (data == 2)
>                 {   alert("data :"+data);
>                     document.getElementById("erroremail").innerHTML = "Email id Already Registered!";
>                     flag = 0;
>                     return false;
>                 }
>                 else if (data == 3)
>                 {   alert("data :"+data);
>                     document.getElementById("errorphone").innerHTML = "Phone No  Already Registered!";
>                     flag = 0;
>                     return false;
>                 }
>                 else
>                     document.forms["signup"].submit();
>              }
>             
>         });
```

Answer (score 1):

remove your `event.preventDefault() ;` inside your $.get function and add `event.preventDefault() ;` or `return false;` in your submit function if you just want to prevent the form from submitting

based on jquery documentation http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/
    event.preventDefautl();  is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

therefore we call this method your submit function will stop triggering the default action

Hopes that helps you understand it :)

Answer (score -1):

You are only preventing the form from submitting when there is a response or subdomain. You need to add `event.preventDefault()` at the top of the event callback.

```
$("#add_plan_subscriptions").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var flag = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason why the form get submitted is because in the last two lines of the code  you posted it you **return true**;

**Make it return false;**

The last two lines of the code you posted is like this

```
return true;
});
```

instead make it like this

```
 return false;
});
```

and also try removing your return true; in that exact line and replace it with event.preventDefault();